# Qt stylesheets and internationalization

Tags: qt, internationalization, stylesheet

I was wondering how others have handled Qt stylesheets that differ slightly between locales. In my case, the differences are in font selection and some minor layout tweaks. The differences are so few that it would be nice if there were some selector syntax that I could use to make the few exceptions where needed. I did not see how I could do this since the QWidget's locale property doesn't convert to a QString.

While I could certainly load a different stylesheet based on locale, I'd prefer to not duplicate so much stylesheet code between the locales. Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

To use selectors I added my own property "cssLocale" via

```
setProperty("cssLocale", QLocale().name());
```

I've already subclassed QMainWindow and QDialog so I set it up in their constructor. Each top-level widget gets the property set.

In the stylesheet, you can do

```
*[cssLocale="ru_RU"] #titleBar {
```

(the widget named "titleBar" which is a descendant of any widget with cssLocale="ru_RU")

Answer (score 0):

QLocale does return a QString, namely of the country-region type, see:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#name

You could implement a simple helper function to simply select a different stylesheet or load an additional one that overwrites rules from the default one.

Comment: Right, but how do you write a selector to get QLocale::name()? I tried QWidget[locale="en_US"] and QWidget[locale.name="en_US"] and neither worked. I know the latter is invalid stylesheet, but I was hopeful.

Comment: You don't write a selector, you write another stylesheet with the changes and load it if the locale isn't the default one. Or you can load a different stylesheet altoguether. I don't believe you can add a selector like that.

Comment: Ok. That's my original question. Is there a better way of handling a one line locale-related change to a stylesheet? It seems less than ideal to copy/paste the whole stylesheet to a new file. I would agree with you if the changes were more significant.

Comment: You don't need to copy the whole thing. Simply add the few rules that you wish to change to a new stylesheet and load that stylesheet after the original one if the locale is not 'en_US' or whatever your default is. The previous rules from the first stylesheet will (should) be overwritten.

Comment: So you're basically saying to just concatenate the contents of the locale-specific stylesheet to the main stylesheet before calling QApplication::setStylesheet. That certainly seems like it should work for me. I'll keep this question open a little longer in case there are other ideas, but this is better than what I had been doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's any QLocale-specific stuff that you can do to make this easier, but you could do some QString magic along these lines:

```
QString styleSheet = "foo { background: %1; }";

qApp->setStyleSheet( styleSheet.arg(whatIReallyWantTheBackgroundToBe()) );
```

Then whenever you need to change the style sheet, you can call setStyleSheet() again and just pass a different parameter to the [.arg()](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qstring.html#arg) function without duplicating the rest of your string.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there was some cool Qt way of handling this, but your solution and the other one will certainly work.